# Excel VBA: Store and retrieve content of a richtextbox in an userform

Tags: excel, vba, richtextbox, userform, rtf

I made an userform to fill a table in Excel. Then I thought, instead of a normal textbox I could use a richtextbox for the "little extra".
But somehow I can't find a way to retrieve the RTF code. I can store the code to a cell like:

`"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \uc1  \pard\f0\fs24\lang1031 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea } "`

But I can't find a way to retrieve the formatted text into the richtextbox, when I reopen the userform.

Can you help me please?

What I already did:
I tried to work with SelRTF and other Parameters and googled a lot.

I was expecting to store the RTF code and load the code again when opening the userform with the richtextbox to generate the formatted text out of it.

Comment: using an InkEdit Control, your should use InkEdit1.TextRTF = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \uc1  \pard\f0\fs24\lang1031 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea } "

Comment: thank you, that works. but it's not possible to insert a picture (e.g. a screenshot) in the textbox, right? if I paste one, it's not there anymore after reopening the userform.

Comment: ah no, that was my fault, the picture is just too "big" to be stored in one cell